Decoding Apache Phoenix Table Column Name using HBase API
I am working on a UseCase where in I need to read the data created from Phoenix table using Hbase API. However while reading the data from Hbase API I am getting data in encoded form.
All the columns names are in the below format. Looking for some help to decode this into the actual column name defined during the creation of table.
table_hbase
Any help will be highly appreciated.
I am able to decode the Timestamp columns using  this method but need some help to decode Column name. One thing which I have observed is that the column names are decoded using Column Families and also having a kind of sequence.
encoded_column_names
Thanks,
Nish
